# use malloc for double pointer in C90

Tags: c, pointers, struct, realloc, c89

I'm trying to create an array of a struct but I don't know it size at the beginning.

```
struct MyStruct** thing;
size_t thing_len = 0;
thing = (struct MyStruct**) malloc(thing_len * sizeof(struct MyStruct*));
//...
thing_len += 1
thing = (struct MyStruct**) realloc(thing_len * sizeof(struct MyStruct*));
```

When I do that `thing` gets the type `MyStruct*` instead of `MyStruct**` and contains `0x0`. But when I do

```
struct MyStruct* thing;
size_t thing_len = 0;
thing = malloc(thing_len * sizeof(struct MyStruct));
//...
thing_len += 1
thing = realloc(thing_len * sizeof(struct MyStruct));
```

It works!!

I don't know if it changes something but I am using `-ansi` and `-pedantic` options.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: It is always a good idea to read the documentation to the functions used.

Comment: C89, C90, ansi? What do you want? And 1st of all, why not C11, the current Standard version?

Comment: On warnings: Use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to include stdlib.h

Comment: I have to use C89 because it's an exercice

Answer (score 4):

In your code

```
  realloc(thing_len * sizeof(struct MyStruct*));
```

is a wrong call to the function. You must use the format <sup>[*Check the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc).*]</sup>

```
 realloc(<old pointer>, new size);
```

That said, a format like

```
 oldPointer = realloc (oldPointer, newSize);
```

is a very *dangerous* piece of code. In case `realloc()` fails, you'll end up losing the original pointer also!!

The prescribed way to use `realloc()` is

```
 tempPointer = realloc (oldPointer, newSize);  //store the return
 if (tempPointer)                              // is it success?
 {
        oldPointer = tempPointer;              // cool, put it back to the variable you want
 }
             //--> here, whether or not realloc is success, you still got a _valid_ pointer.
```

Comment: In many cases, a program will be doomed to die a miserable death in any case where `realloc()` would fail.  Including an explicit `if (!oldPointer) out_of_memory_error()` may be better than dying from a SIGSEGV, but keeping a copy of the old pointer around in cases where code is going to die anyway isn't necessarily helpful.  It's too bad there aren't standard functions for "malloc_or_die", "realloc_or_die", etc. since they could eliminate the need for a lot of redundant error-handling code.